# get the directory where app starts to run (c++ code)

Tags: c++, ios

I hope to get the current working path of app.
I know the objective-c code.
But I prefer c++ code.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getcwd` function:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    char *cwd;
    if ((cwd = getcwd(NULL, 64)) == NULL) {
        perror("pwd");
        exit(2);
    }
    std::cout <<  cwd << std::endl;;
    free(cwd); /* free memory allocated by getcwd() */
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you could use [Boost.FileSystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) and the `current_path()` method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::path p = boost::filesystem::current_path();
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_getcwd` is a Windows only thing. `getcwd` is POSIX and I think should work fine on iOS.

Comment: Yup, didn't notice `ios` tag, thanks!

Comment: +1 for boost filesystem library.

Comment: getcwd doesn't work on ios